# android getColorFilter() for api 9

Tags: android, colors, imagebutton, colorfilter

I have an image button in my activity and I set it's color filter with the function `setColorFilter()` and for some reason I want to get that color back and compare it to do some function, I tried to use `getColorFilter()` but it's for api 16 and above and I'm currently targeting api 9, is there any way or another function to do it at api 9 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DrawableCompat.getColorFilter(Drawable drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#getColorFilter(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) which is added to support library since version 24.1.0.

You need to add the support library to your dependencies block of your `build.gradle` to use it, like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way to get the color filter. But you can get it some other way like while you setting the color filter you have to set the same object as the tag to the image button then later you can get it by calling the getTag() method.

**Example:**

```
//While setting        
imageButton.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
imageButton.setTag(colorFilter);

//While retrieving
ColorFilter colorFilter = (ColorFilter) imageButton.getTag();
```

Comment: What if it's set from XML (Which is should be?)

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns this is a hack not a direct solution. I didn't tried for xml values...But I think it may work. You can try it on your own and comment the result